# Recycle windows workflow after changes on workflow activity

Tags: asp.net, workflow-foundation

I used WWF on my web project, on this  project I have several workflows and visitor will fill forms and then form will post to technical people to do their job and some other state ...

When I change workflow and create new activity or state , when run ( continue ) all workflows that persist on db before changes , will throw errors.

```
    Server was unable to process request. ---> System.InvalidOperationException: Workflow with id "82b0cb6c-d6b7-43cd-9071-04a1078954ec" not found in state persistence store.
   at System.Workflow.Runtime.Hosting.PersistenceDBAccessor.RetrieveInstanceState(Guid instanceStateId, Guid ownerId, DateTime timeout)
   at System.Workflow.Runtime.Hosting.SqlWorkflowPersistenceService.LoadWorkflowInstanceState(Guid id)
   at System.Workflow.Runtime.WorkflowRuntime.InitializeExecutor(Guid instanceId, CreationContext context, WorkflowExecutor executor, WorkflowInstance workflowInstance)
   at System.Workflow.Runtime.WorkflowRuntime.Load(Guid key, CreationContext context, WorkflowInstance workflowInstance)
   at System.Workflow.Runtime.WorkflowRuntime.GetWorkflow(Guid instanceId)
   at System.Workflow.Activities.WorkflowWebService.Invoke(Type interfaceType, String methodName, Boolean isActivation, Object[] parameters)
```

how can I recycle old workflows after changes?

Thanks

Comment: Can you show some simple code demonstrating how you change the workflow?

Comment: I change the design view of workflow and add or delete some activities. for example if I add a new code activity after compile worlkflow project and when try to run workflow from client project I get that error message

Answer (score 0):

Your error looks pretty specific there. The workflow with your particular GUID doesn't exist.

Changing a workflow definition does not change existing workflows. They will continue to execute their predetermined definitions unless you initiate an actual change process on them. You'll want to dig into Dynamic Workflow Updates if this is what you want to accomplish.